# Microsoft Graph api - Missing 'none' (or not any) functionality for $filter

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I'm trying to retrieve any message that I *haven't* specifically categorized but there isn't a `none` filter option for Microsoft Graph. I tried to invert the `any` filter by using the following call:

```
/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=categories/any(c:c ne 'MyCategory')
```

However, this will still return items containing `'MyCategory'`. Is there another method by which I can retrieve items that don't have that category set on them? (Returning items with no category set at all is not exclusive enough).

I had contemplated using custom extensions, however, the filter for extensions also lacks a none option.

Answer (score 0):

try this

im not sure is this is your request

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/?$select=categories

Comment: Unfortunately, no. That will select categores, but I need to return a list of messages that do not contain a specific category (I'm using that as a user-readable means of knowing that our application has processed specific messages).

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't a good way to do negative comparisons like this within the API itself.

The reason `any` doesn't work is that your query translates to "include the message if any of it's categories are not 'MyCategory'". That would include messages with no categories (i.e. `null`) as well as message with any other category (i.e. a message with both `MyCategory` and `Blue Category` would match the filter).

Your best bet is using Open Extensions. These allow you to add application-specific data to Graph resources that you can filter against.

Comment: I have tried with extensions, but seem unable to retrieve a list of messages that don't have the extension present (as with categories). Any idea how I filter that?

Comment: You would need to iterate over the messages once in order to populate the extensions. I often use multiple extensions, one to denote that my app cares about the object and another to hold custom data. That way I can pull all of the objects related to my app and hydrate my app from the aditional extension.

Comment: I guessed that might be the case, but it makes what I want to use categories/extensions for useless - I wanted to mark items that have been handled by a subscription so I can easily check what hasn't been handled by looking for unmarked items. If I have to manually check every item, that's less efficient. I can't believe they haven't added inversion of these filters.

Comment: That is what Delta queries are for, they return only the records that have changed since the last time you queried a given resource.

Comment: Yeah, I guessed as much. I really didn't want to have to check potentially thousands of messages using the first delta query to obtain the initial change key.